# AWS RDS Unable to Configure "Database Mail" Option

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, rds

[image: Database Mail option Error Message in RDS]

HI,

We are trying to send emails using "Database Mail" option from SQL SERVER Management Studio. The same is possible in our On premise server,when we try to configure "Database Mail " option from Wizard in RDS it says that "User Does not have permission". The screen shot showed above for your reference. Is it not possible to configure Database Mail in RDS?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing is because the `master` user that is created when you set up the RDS instance doesn't have `sysadmin` privileges. [See here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html#SQLServer.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.Limits) for more info. That wizard can only be used by sysadmin users.

In some cases you would be able to [generate a script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh245116.aspx#sectionToggle2) to apply on the server, instead of using the wizard. However this isn't an option in RDS as it [doesn't currently support Database Mail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html#SQLServer.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport) at all.